# Will declaring a property in an ObjC category override a property of the same name that's declared on the public interface?

Tags: objective-c

This is not intended to solve any particular problem, just looking to understand the nuances of properties in Objc.

say I have a class `Dude`

```
# Dude.h

@interface Dude: NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber *height;

@end
```

I extend the class in the implementation file but change the attributes.

```
# Dude.m

@interface Dude()

@property (readwrite, atomic) NSNumber *height;

@end


@implementation Dude
@end
```

I get an error.

> 'atomic' attribute on property 'height' does not match the property
>   inherited from 'Dude'

So what is actually going on here. Is the property on the extension the same property? Am I just overriding the accessors?

Also when I change the order so that the public interface is `readwrite` but the private interface is `readonly` I get the error:

> Illegal redeclaration of property in class extension 'Dude' (attribute
>   must be 'readwrite', while its primary must be 'readonly')

This makes me think it's an entire redeclaration but now I am less sure about what is actually happening. Looking for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apple’s [*The Objective-C Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2), they describe “extensions” as follows, using the redeclaration of a property as an example:

> #### Extensions
>
> Class extensions are like anonymous categories, except that the methods they declare must be implemented in the main `@implementation` block for the corresponding class. Using the Clang/LLVM 2.0 compiler, you can also declare properties and instance variables in a class extension.
>
> A common use for class extensions is to redeclare property that is publicly declared as read-only privately as readwrite:
>
> ```
> @interface MyClass : NSObject
> @property (retain, readonly) float value;
> @end
>
> // Private extension, typically hidden in the main implementation file.
> @interface MyClass ()
> @property (retain, readwrite) float value;
> @end
> ```
>
> ...

So, as illustrated here, this pattern is to “redeclare” a property. It’s the same property, though. You only redeclare a property when you want the compiler to synthesize a private setter even though the public interface is declared as `readonly`. If you don’t redeclare the property as `readwrite` in the extension, a setter will not be synthesized at all.

Your various warnings actually illustrate the fact that we’re dealing with the same property, because are merely examples where the nature of your redeclaration isn’t compatible with what was included in the public interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of this more like a public and private interface.

The interface declared in the .h file is the public interface for your class.
So if you have a reason to declare a property readonly it makes sense there.

The nameless category (Dude()) in your .m file is your private sight on the properties. So you can specify readwrite here to make your class able to change the property internally but not to the outside world.

You can also use these declaration for your methods to declare a public interface in .h and private methods in interface Dude() in .m.

The combination in your public and private interface must make sense, you can't declare a public property readwrite and say internally it is just readonly ...

And finally this is Objective-C: this is just for your editor and compiler. Everything that exists can be accessed even if it is declared some kind of private.

Comment: @JoeSusnick this is correct on the pattern that you are playing with. Making extra clear: when you're triggering the errors, it's because your private declaration is incompatible with the public one. Tom's example of making something publicly `readonly` and privately `readwrite` is common and works fine. The underlying property you end up with is the same property, with different levels of access/visibility.